# Getting text from angular input elements in Protractor

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, protractor

The angular Input controls doesn't let me get values directly by using getText() in protractor.

```
<input ng-switch-when="TextBox" ng-if="::!field.uiControlInfo.multiLine" ng-model="field.input[0].value" ng-focus="onFieldFocus(field, 0, $event)" ng-blur="onFieldBlur(field, true, $event)" ng-readonly="field.isReadOnly || state.wait" ng-change="onFieldChange(field, false)" cp-form-view-formatter="field" placeholder="" id="InvoiceNumber" class="cp-flex-fill cp-formview-field-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-style="{ 'text-align': field.uiControlInfo.fieldAlignment.toLowerCase() }" ng-keydown="fieldKeyDown($event, field, 0)" autocomplete="off" style="text-align: left;">

var element=element(By.id());
element.getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

This is the ideal way of getting input value from the input elements. But this doesn't work for angular elements.

**"angular.element(some_element_id).scope.field.input[0].value"**

This gives the value out of the angular elements in browser console.

Can somebody help me with how can i write the same in Protractor??

Comment: Please add the corresponding HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
element(by.id('#id')).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
element.getAttribute('value') //for input field
```

See docs [Protractor getAttribute](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.